# Windows 7 Heroku Python Django LNK2001 psycopg2 error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I'm following heroku's instructions on how to build a web project using python and django on windows and haven't been able to figure out my LNK2001 psycopg2 error.

Tutorial links:

- [Link to Heroku's instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction)
- [Link to Heroku's link to Python on Windows](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/)

I am running this command:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt --allow-all-external
```

Here is the error output:

```
   Creating library build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\psycopg\_psycopg.lib and object build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\psycopg\_psycopg.exp

pqpath.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PQclear referenced in function _pq_raise

connection_int.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQclear

cursor_type.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQclear

...

    build\lib.win32-2.7\psycopg2\_psycopg.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 62 unresolved externals

error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

----------------------------------------
←[31m    Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\mariss~1.nie\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-vojshb\\p
ycopg2\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\
ariss~1.nie\appdata\local\temp\pip-nuj6xa-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\use
s\mariss~1.nie\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-vojshb\psycopg2←[0m
```

I am using the following:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Python 2.7.8 32-bit
- Pip
- Virtual Environment (virtualenv)
- PostgreSQL 9.4
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 32-bit

I've put `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\` in my PATH variable.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I changed install postgres on 32-bit and I have passed this error.

I accidentally install a 64-bit install postgres 9.4.1. After that, any attempt at compiling and linking this error was issued. Trying to change the compiler to mingv32, I noticed that he had an error in the library libpg.dll (unknown format). Then I uninstalled and installed systems for postgres 32-bit version 9.4 in the root directory (c:/postgreSQL). The problem has been passed.

In my case, the configuration had the same, but I install an additional MS Visual C++ Express 10 version.

Configuration:

- Windows 7 (64-bit)
- Python 3.4
- Postgres 9.4.1 (re-installed to) --> Postgres 9.4 MS
- Visual C++ Express 10 version
- PIP
- Virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Created a Linux VM and followed the steps again in that environment. Worked great. No idea why I couldn't get it working in Windows.